# Get existing object by reading out of XML using Java (JAXB)

Tags: java, parsing, object, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have some problems describing my problem.

I have an XML-File with names of existing classes in my project. 
E.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MetaClasses>
    <MetaClass ID="1">  
        <Meta>ExistingClassName</Meta>
    </MetaClass>
    <MetaClass ID="2">
    ...
    </MetaClass>
</MetaClasses>
```

And i need the corresponding existing class, because i need to work with this class.

I don't want to create a new object, like `MetaClass meta = new MetaClass();`, i want the real class with its real attributes, properties and methods, since the XML ClassName is just simple text.
I need the properties of that class to proceed my project.

I hope you were able to get my problem correctly or rather i explained it correctly :P

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by myself. 
Maybe someone has the same problem and I could help you with my answer.

I had to take the String inside the `<Meta>`-Tag and did this:

```
Class classMeta = Class.forName(string);
Bean beanMeta = (Bean) classMeta.newInstance();
```

Then I was able to work with this Meta-Class.